# No file error even though file is present

Tags: python, python-2.6

I am getting the following error. I can actually see "build/envsetup.sh" from buid root directory given below but I keep getting this error.

Is there anything wrong with the following line?

```
  makecommand=Popen(['source build/envsetup.sh'],stderr=PIPE)"
```

---

BUILD_ROOT_DIR
    /local/mnt/workspace/AU

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 266, in <module>
    main()
  File "test.py", line 263, in main
    cherrypick(base_change,SCRIPT_ROOT)
  File "test.py", line 204, in cherrypick
    makebuild(change)
  File "test.py", line 97, in makebuild
    makecommand=Popen(['source build/envsetup.sh'],stderr=PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 633, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1139, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: You've tagged this question with "python-2.7" whereas the stack trace above shows "python2.6" -- this is suspicious. Is this a SCons script?

Comment: Are you sure your current working directory contains "build" directory?

Comment: @Johnsyweb -- oops sorry..its 2.6.5..its a python script..

Comment: @jdi - currently working directory is build_root_dir,it does have build directory which contains envsetup.sh

Comment: OK, I have retagged. Are you sure `${PWD}` = `/local/mnt/workspace/AU`?

Comment: @Johnsyweb - Yes, pwd is /local/mnt/workspace/AU

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the additional parameter: shell=True

code:

```
 makecommand=Popen('source build/envsetup.sh',stderr=PIPE, shell=True)
```

There's a disclaimer in the python [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) that this could lead to a security issue depending on the context of your program.

IMO, you should probably pipe both stdout and stderr to separate variables and use the communicate method to invoke the command. You'll be able to handle the output and error more readily.

code:

```
 cmd_out, cmd_err = Popen('source build/envsetup.sh', stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True).communicate()
```

Best of luck!

Comment: You should replace the list with a string

Comment: Oh it should still work, but yes, that should simplify it for him.

Comment: @Paul -   I keep getting this error when using the command as "    makecommand= Popen(['source build/envsetup.sh'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True).communicate()" stderr=makecommand.communicate()[1]
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'communicate'

Comment: @PaulRigor - never mind,I figured out..thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 3):

When you call Popen, you can either pass a string command with `shell=True` or you are expected to pass a list. You should try changing the command to:

```
makecommand=Popen(['source', 'build/envsetup.sh'],stderr=PIPE)
```

*I am only commenting on Popen usage, not anything related to the actual command you are running.*

Answer (score 0):

`source` is a shell built-in, not an executable file. Try `"sh build/envsetup.sh"` instead. And also what jdi said.